# MDriven | Modlr opens in XML editor even though the default is set to Modlr

Tags: mdriven

I've been facing an issue with my project wherein on double click of the .ecomdl file instead of opening in the Modlr, the file opens in an XML editor.

As you can see in the attached screenshot, **Modlr Files** is set as the default program to open .ecomdl still Visual Studio opens it up in an XML editor.

[image: Default File]

I've tried to reset my visual studio settings too, reinstalled visual studio, MDriven

Have anyone of you ever faced a similar issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the project file that has this:

```
<None Include="YOURMODEL.ecomdl">
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</None>
```

When it should look like this:

```
<None Include="YOURMODEL.ecomdl">
</None>
```

Comment: Worked like a CHARM! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this has happened before. Trying to remember what I did to solve it a couple of years ago, but nothing comes to mind.

BUT - this also happened to me only a couple of days ago because the latest Framework installation has problems with an older version of VS2017.

Make sure you update your VS2017 to 15.9.28.

Then, uninstall the framwork (VS not running of course) and then reinstall. After that, it worked for me.

I think you can also try switching between Modlr files (default) to another editor and then back again.

If this doesn't solve your problem I'll look into other solutions.

Best regards,
Lars (MDriven)

Comment: Tried all the above. I'm using VS 2019. Been facing this issue for about a year now - just crossed my "enough is enough" stage and am now trying to desperately find a solution. I have 5 projects in total and among them, the Modlr opens perfectly in 2 and the other 3 - I have to use the "Open With" to open the diagram in the Modlrl. I've gone as far as formatting my system too. Nothing worked.

Comment: Also, the 3 projects in question were created using a copy of another project (to avoid setting up the environment from scratch). I've done a global search to check for keywords related to the older project to check if there are any residual words or left out keywords. Couldn't find anything.